# Error: Too many nested views or possible circular reference of views referenced in query. Only 8 levels of nested views are allowed

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Documentation says that Standard SQL in BigQUery can support 100 levels of nested views. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#limitations

But I am hitting **Error: Too many nested views or possible circular reference of views referenced in query. Only 8 levels of nested views are allowed.** issue when I have created 9 levels of views in Standard SQL.

How can I exceed 8 levels of nested views in BigQuery?

Comment: looks like it is `or possible circular reference of views referenced in query` that is your issue! without having more details on your query / views it is hard to help here

Comment: Hey but why does the  error say only 8 levels of nested queries are allowed when according to bigquery documentation, 100 levels of nested views are possible using standard sql.

Comment: Not sure back in May, but as for now, the limitation for nested views in BigQuery is [16 levels](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#limitations)